# Drupal sends emails to Hotmail but not to other accounts

Tags: emails

I have a problem when Drupal sends email messages. I use the Rules module for doing it.

When the email is sent to a Hotmail account, the email is sent successfully; with other accounts (e.g. Yahoo, Gmail), the email is not received. The "recent log entries" shows the email as successfully sent, but the account doesn't receive it.

Answer (score 1):

Likely the problem is not in drupal, but in server environment. You could use [Drupal SMTP Support](http://drupal.org/project/smtp) module to bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the MIME Format. See [Multi-part message in MIME format wrong plain text format](http://drupal.org/node/319562) and the patch reported there.

Comment: My problem is that the email only recieve hotmail.. but when i send email for other accounts like a yahoo o gmail don't receive. My question is.. Why? :D